# Does anyone know of an OSX integrated shell plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, shell

I be been poking around for about 15 minutes now and I am about to give up, But thought I would try here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [PathTools](http://code.google.com/p/pathtools/). You can even install it via the Eclipse Marketplace (found under the Help menu), I think.